# SpringBoot Hibernate. Unable to GET findAll and findById in Postman, Swager, api link for OneToMany, ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm unable to get response in Postman. It becomes an infinite loop I think. The models are: dish, category. One category had multiple dishes.
[image]

Before add Dish (id, category), it behave normal like this
[image]
Here is the Dish and Category model
[image]
[image]
Here is one of the Controller
[image]
The post dish working great, but the search is not. Anyone know how to solve it? (The db I use is Postgres)

Edit: I solved it. Using @JsonBackReference and @JsonManageReference

Answer (score 0):

Your **Dish & Category** are related entities.

Try having **@JsonIgnore** annotation in your Dish class for Category field or the other way around.

Also, always use a DTO instead of returning the actual DB object in the Rest-call.

Comment: I tried your way, put @JsonIgnore on the Category, the result is this: ```[{"name":"breakfast","id":1},{"name":"noon","id":2}]```
No Dish.
But for the Dish, it return status 500 Whitelabel Error Page